# Extending the existing User model in Django

Tags: python, django, authentication

Let's say I have an app that has 3 kinds of user

- Employee with fields like `work_number`, `department` etc.
- Member with fields like `phone_number`, .....
- Agent with fields like `company_name`,.....

They're different.

I write models like this:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    department = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    .......

class Member(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    .......

class Agent(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    .......
```

Now I can :

```
u = User.objects.get(username='xxxx')
u.employee // it works...
```

but, ONE user has THREE profiles (employee,member,agent) !!!

It's not matches my business, the business role is ONE user could be and must be only one kind of 3 profiles.

What's the best way to solve this?

Comment: So you're saying you want a User to only be one of three profiles? How are the profiles created?

Comment: The registration form creates one user and the profile

Answer (score 1):

Why not have a single profile with a role associated (even if certain fields will never be filled for a specific role)?

You can handle the validation through forms and instead having 3 different models you would have 3 different forms.

Comment: This is the best solution because you can than just go to user.profile instead of user.employee, user.member etc.